# Node ORM hasMany association

Tags: node.js, orm, associations, node-orm2

I want to list out all of user ConversationData (ONE User HAS MANY CovnresationData), but i got 'undefined' when i followed tutorial on official site. Help, guys!

```
 var User = db.define("user", {
      name      : String,
      surname   : String,
      avatar    : String,
      username  : String,
      token     : String
    }, {
      autoSave: true
    });

var Conversation = db.define("conversations", {
  name       : Number,
  createdAt  : Date,
  updatedAt  : Date
});
var ConversationData = db.define("conversation_data", {
  user_id         : Number,
  conversation_id : Number
});


db.sync();



 User.hasMany('conversationsData', ConversationData, {}, {
  autoFetch: true
});
User.find({id: 1}).first(function(err, asda) {
  cconsole.log(asda.conversationsData);

});
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(orm/postgres) SELECT "t1"."user_id", "t1"."conversation_id", "t1"."id" FROM "conversation_data" "t1" JOIN "user_conversationsData" "t2" ON "t2"."conversationsdata_id" = "t1"."id" WHERE "t2"."user_id" = 1
undefined
```

Request seems to me completely wrong. it must Join user and conversation data tables, as i understand..

Answer (score 0):

At least as far as I've seen with MySQL, ORM handles `hasMany` relationships by creating a 'merge' table, in your case it is likely what you see as `user_conversationsData`. This table should have 3 columns, `id` (generated, ignore it), `user_id` to map to the `Users` table, and `conversationdata_id` to map to the `conversationData` table.

You have `autofetch` on, what ORM will do is fetch the `User`, and then fetch the `conversationdata_id's` and the `conversationData's` by joining the extra merge-table to the `conversationData` table. This is the query you see.

To access the conversationData, you should be able to see it as a property `userInstance.conversationDatas`. If that doesn't work, try calling `console.dir(Object.keys(userInstance))` to see what's there.